# How to find the probability of a tie.

Tags: probability

Questions:
21 management participants are required to vote for an event theme. There are 5 event themes for selection. Each participants can cast 2 votes but they are not allowed to vote for the same theme twice.

What is the chances of a tie?

Comment: There is no tie if one theme has the most votes. Figure that probability out, then find the compliment.

Comment: Does "one can cast" mean that one is obliged to cast 2 votes, or one can choose to cast only one vote or even no vote at all?

Comment: Each participant is obligated to cast 2 votes.